# RuntimeError: HDF5File - describe

Tags: python-bob

I want to reproduct the code of cross modal focal loss cvpr2021. But I ran into some difficulties and I don't know where to find the solution. The difficulties are  the following.

---

File "/data/run01/scz1974/chenjiawei/bob.paper.cross_modal_focal_loss_cvpr2021/src/bob.io.stream/bob/io/stream/stream_file.py", line 117, in get_stream_shape
descriptor = self.hdf5_file.describe(data_path)
RuntimeError: HDF5File - describe ('/HOME/scz1974/run/yanghao/fasdata/HQ-WMCA/MC-PixBiS-224/preprocessed/face-station/26.02.19/1_01_0064_0000_00_00_000-48a8d5a0.hdf5'): C++ exception caught: 'Cannot find dataset `BASLER_BGR' at` /HOME/scz1974/run/yanghao/fasdata/HQ-WMCA/MC-PixBiS-224/preprocessed/face-station/26.02.19/1_01_0064_0000_00_00_000-48a8d5a0.hdf5:''

Answer (score 0):

The instructions assumes that you have obtained the raw dataset which has all the data channels. The preprocessed files only contains grayscale and swir differences. If you want to use grayscale and one of the swir differences as two channels you can skip the preprocessing part as given in the documentation.

Comment: I just run the instruction: './bin/bob pad vanilla-pad \ /bob/paper/cross_modal_focal_loss_cvpr2021/config/Method/Pipeline.py \-o <folder_to_save_results> -vvv'. And I followed the 'Running experiments with the trained model' of 'running_cmfl_hqwmca.rst' to update the path to preprocessed files, annotations, protocol and the CNN model path in the config/Method/Pipeline.py. My understanding is that the instruction is for preprocessed files. But why do you say there is the preprocessing part in Pipeline.py?

Comment: You have to point `PREPROCESSED_DIR` to the path of the preprocessed files.Also have to set other variables for the protocols.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I updated the variables in the Pipeline.py. And the error is what I asked.

Comment: Could you please give me a demo of Pipeline.py for the preprocessed data？ I don't know how to modify the Pipeline.py. Thank you very much.